# sed Commands Pattern

Tags: linux, text-processing, sed

I want make a script to comment at specific moment

```
#a6712376789
aeaasdfsdgf
asdffdgjf
anfth
#v1781289123


#8765123ha71
kldfgnkajfb
xcmbvnkzv
zxjvb
#9054123h273


#a64464v79870
poiyghjf
okjfcjnh
ghcfyhjb
#b9764863m647


#g17862378138
wsdvbgnhm
rfvbgnhm
frvgbki
#781t23g21341
```

Its possible make this appen

```
#a6712376789
#aeaasdfsdgf
#asdffdgjf
#anfth
#v1781289123


#8765123ha71
kldfgnkajfb
xcmbvnkzv
zxjvb
#9054123h273


#a64464v79870
poiyghjf
okjfcjnh
ghcfyhjb
#b9764863m647


#g17862378138
wsdvbgnhm
rfvbgnhm
frvgbki
#781t23g21341
```

Because i tryed this

```
sed -i -e '/^#a64464v79870$/,/^#b9764863m647$/!d;//d' -e 's/^/#&/' Untitled\ Document\ 1
```

and this appen the file get only this conent

```
#aeaasdfsdgf
#asdffdgjf
#anfth
```

Comment: You are explicitly deleting the lines not in that region, so no wonder the lines disappear.

Comment: i dont understand so much about scripting , its second time , i want to comment at middle of the already comment numbers and save in same file and keep the other non-changed on same place, sry my englsih

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

`sed '/#a6712376789/,/#v1781289123/s/^#*/#/' /file/name`

Add `-i` to edit the file, rather than just writing it to `stdout`

Comment: its possible change "#" to ";" but without change the #a6712376789 and #v1781289123 # ?

Comment: assuming all the lines start with a lowercase letter... `sed '/#a6712376789/,/#v1781289123/s/^\([a-z]\)/;\1/' /file/name`

Comment: Work again TY one more time!